# Python parsing query string to list

Tags: python, flask

I have a form that submits data to the server that looks like the following:

```
videos[0][type]=Vimeo&
  videos[0][moments][0][time]=11&
  videos[0][moments][0][lng]=111&
  videos[0][moments][0][lat]=111&
  videos[0][moments][1][time]=222&
  videos[0][moments][1][lng]=222&
  videos[0][moments][1][lat]=222&
videos[1][type]=YouTube&
  videos[1][moments][0][time]=111&
  videos[1][moments][0][lng]=111&
  videos[1][moments][0][lat]=111
...
```

I am using Flask and I would like to be able to loop through the `videos` and `moments` but it seems like there isn't a way to do that. I tried looking for libraries on Google but my Google-fu is weak tonight.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

**EDIT**: Based on lazy1's answer, I modified his/her code to

```
def add(root, path, value):
  for part in path[:-1]:
    root = root.setdefault(part, {})
  root[path[-1]] = value

def parse(s):
  items = {}
  for key, value in parse_qsl(s):
    parts = filter(None, re.split('[\[\]]', key))
    name = parts[0]
    if name not in items: 
      items[name] = {}
    add(items[name], parts[1:], value)
  return items
```

that will generate a hash:

```
{'map': {'title': 'orange'}, 'videos': {'1': {'moments': {'0': {'lat': '111', 'lng': '111', 'time': '111'}}, 'type': 'YouTube'}, '0': {'moments': {'1': {'lat': '222', 'lng': '222', 'time': '222'}, '0': {'lat': '111', 'lng': '111', 'time': '11'}}, 'type': 'Vimeo'}}}
```

for a query that looks like:

```
map[title]=orange&
videos[0][type]=Vimeo&
  videos[0][moments][0][time]=11&
  videos[0][moments][0][lng]=111&
  videos[0][moments][0][lat]=111&
  videos[0][moments][1][time]=222&
  videos[0][moments][1][lng]=222&
  videos[0][moments][1][lat]=222&
videos[1][type]=YouTube&
  videos[1][moments][0][time]=111&
  videos[1][moments][0][lng]=111&
  videos[1][moments][0][lat]=111
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [urlparse.parse_qsl](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qsl) to get the query parameters. However you'll need manually to construct the video objects.

Example implementation can be:

```
def add(root, path, value):
    for part in path[:-1]:
        root = root.setdefault(part, {})
    root[path[-1]] = value

def parse(s):
    videos = {}
    for key, value in parse_qsl(s):
        parts = filter(None, re.split('[\[\]]', key))
        insert(videos, parts[1:], value)
    return videos
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use [formencode](http://formencode.org/) and can change the format of your keys to:

```
map.title=orange&
videos-0.type=Vimeo&
  videos-0.moments-0.time=11&
  videos-0.moments-0.lng=111&
  videos-0.moments-0.lat=111&
  videos-0.moments-1.time=222&
  videos-0.moments-1.lng=222&
  videos-0.moments-1.lat=222&
videos-1.type=YouTube&
  videos-1.moments-0.time]=111&
  videos-1.moments-0.lng]=111&
  videos-1.moments-0.lat]=111
```

You can use:

```
from urlparse import parse_qsl
from formencode.variabledecode import variable_decode

def parse(s):
   return variable_decode(parse_qsl(s))
```

To give:

```
{
 'map': {'title': 'orange'}, 
 'videos': [ 
   {
     'moments': [ {'lat': '111', 'lng': '111', 'time': '11'}, 
                  {'lat': '222', 'lng': '222', 'time': '222'}],
     'type': 'Vimeo'
    }, {
    'moments': [ {'lat': '111', 'lng': '111', 'time': '111'} ],

    'type': 'YouTube'
   }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I will be using that library. I don't like the format of the names but I guess I can live with it. :)