# python calling methods of class using different ways

Tags: python, oop, class, object

I have some class:

```
class RSA:
 CONST_MOD=2
 def __init__(self):
  print "created"

 def fast_powering(self,number,power,mod):
  print "powering"
```

I want to instantiate it and call method fast_powering:

```
 def main():
  obj=RSA() # here instant of class is created 
  val=obj.fast_powering(10,2,obj.CONST_MOD)  #  and we call method of object
  print val
```

And it works fine!

But I found that  I can do it a little bit different way too, like:

```
def main():
 obj=RSA #do we create a link to the class without creating of object , or what?
 val=obj().fast_powering(10,2,obj().CONST_MOD) # and here we do something like
          # calling of static method of class in C++ without class instantiation,
          #  or ?
 print val
```

Sorry, I think a little bit  in C++ way, but anyway 
to my great astonishment it works too! 
What's actually happening here? Which wayn is more preffered? It's some misterious for me.

Thanks in advance for any replies!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, you're doing:

```
obj = RSA
```

which is just binding the name `obj` to whatever was bound to `RSA`, which is the class `RSA` in your instance. Then you're doing:

```
obj().fast_powering(…)
```

Which is equivalent to creating an instance of `RSA` and calling the method `fast_powering` on it. Note that this way, you'll get a new instance of `RSA` on each call, which is probably not what you want. You'll also have noticed, that the `__init__` method has been called in the line cited above. Also consider:

```
>>> class RSA:
...   def __init__(self):
...     print("foo")
... 
>>> obj = RSA
>>> obj() is obj()
foo
foo
False
```

Here we see that the statement `obj() is obj()` in fact creates two objects, which are of course not identical. This is opposed to your first example, as demonstrated using:

```
>>> class RSA:
...   def __init__(self):
...     print("foo")
... 
>>> obj = RSA()
foo
>>> obj is obj
True
```

Comment: +1 For using the right glyph for ellipsis. Just kidding, the answer is great, but I'd wish to see that more.

Answer (score 1):

After `obj = RSA`, both `RSA` and `obj` refer to the same class - you're *not* creating an instance of `RSA`, however. Consider this:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        print 'Foo'

Bar = Foo

Foo()
Bar()
```

Output:

```
Foo
Foo
```

In terms of which way is more preferable: it really depends on what you are trying to do. But in general, the first method is preferable, unless you have a good reason to be using the second method.

Comment: so, if this link is created  Bar= Foo, is instance of class  created?

Comment: @gekannt No, `Bar` is just defined to be the `Foo` class. Notice how `init` is not called when we do `Bar = Foo`.

Answer (score 1):

Well... It turns out that `class RSA` is a instance too so you can store it in variables (which is what your second method is doing), although I need to point out you're not actually doing the same thing in both of them. When you do:

```
val=obj().fast_powering(10,2,obj().CONST_MOD)
```

You are actually calling the RSA's constructor twice (you've got two `obj()` calls), and thus you'll see two "*created*" messages on the console.

There is a lot of weird ways of doing the same thing in Python. For readability sake, I prefer the "regular" way (the one shown on your first method),but here's a quick example of things that are *legally* doable:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class RSA(object):
    CONST_MOD=2
    def __init__(self):
        print "created"

    def fast_powering(self,number,power,mod):
        print "powering"

def method1_good():
    obj=RSA() # here instant of class is created 
    val=obj.fast_powering(10,2,obj.CONST_MOD)  #  and we call method of object
    print val

def method2_bad():
    obj=RSA #do we create a link to the class without creating of object , or what?
    val=obj().fast_powering(10,2,obj().CONST_MOD)
    print val

def method3_badToo():
    getattr(RSA(), "fast_powering")(10,2,RSA().CONST_MOD)

def method4_areYouNuts():
    for key, val in globals().iteritems():
        if isinstance(val, type) and (key == "RSA"):
            obj = val()
            getattr(obj, "fast_powering")(10,2,obj.CONST_MOD)
            break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "Works with method1?"
    method1_good()
    print "Works with method2?"
    method2_bad()
    print "Works with method3?"
    method3_badToo()
    print "Works with method4?"
    method4_areYouNuts()
```

Maybe this may give you some things to look for, such as:
[Globals and Locals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969949/whats-the-difference-between-globals-locals-and-vars)
Gettattr and setattr ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893929/accessing-list-items-with-getattr-setattr-in-python) and [2](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/832252-setattr-getattr-when-use))

And if you want to dig a bit more... the crazy things you can do with [metaclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python)... (explained in one of the best answers I've ever seen in StackOverflow)

Comment: I don't see the second ``obj()`` call actually (second paragraph of yours).

Comment: I copied it from the third "code block" of the question (the second main() example)

Comment: Oh right, I overlooked the ``obj()`` in the arguments, nevermind.