# Get returned by __enter__ in __exit__

Tags: python

For example, i have this code:

```
with MyClass() as x:
    print 'I have only {0}'.format(x)
    with MyClass() as y:
        print 'I have {0} and {1}'.format(x, y)
    print 'Again only {0}'.format(x)
```

`x` and `y` both should be de-initialized after exit of corresponding `with` blocks. Also `x` and `y` aren't instances of `MyClass`.

`__exit__` has only three arguments and each argument is None (if no exception supplied).

How can i determine at `__exit__` which block is just exited and what value was returned by `__enter__`?

(N.B. code should be thread-safe).

---

Example:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        if moon_phase > 0:
            return 123
        else:
            return 456
    def __exit__(self):
        number = what_was_returned_by_enter()
        print 'End of block with', number


 with MyClass() as x:
    print x  # 123
    with MyClass() as y:
        print x, 'and', y  # 123 and 456
    # printed "End of block with 456"
    print x  # 123
 # printed "End of block with 123"
```

Comment: Just keep track of the value you returned by storing it in an instance variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have a custom class handling your context, `self` will be the context manager instance.

You'll need to examine its state (stored at `__init__()` creation time or when `__enter__()` was called) to determine which one you just exited.

The following example stores the return value of `__enter__` on the instance so you can retrieve it again when `__exit__` is being called:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        if moon_phase > 0:
            self.returnval = 123
        else:
            self.returnval = 456
        return self.returnval

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        number = self.returnval
        print 'End of block with', number
```

Comment: But if i write nested with statements, `self.returnval` will be rewrited at start of child block and i'll lost value from parent block.

Comment: @werehuman: No, unless you use mutable default arguments on your class or your methods, that is not possible. Each context manager is a separate instance. Please update your question with example code if you want help with figuring out *why* your code is not working in your specific situation.

Comment: You are right, it creates new instance. I am going to read manuals.

Comment: @werehuman: I think [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13478383/1248008) might help you with understanding what's going on in your example.

Comment: @werehuman: I think it's your use of the `moon_phase` global, both of your context managers will return `123` unless `moon_phase` is changed between calls.