# Get __enter__'s return value in __exit__

Tags: python, psycopg2, contextmanager

I'm trying to make a database connection pool behave like a simple connection (`psycopg2`). Kind of like this:

```
from psycopg2.pool import ThreadedConnectionPool    
pool = ThreadedConnectionPool(...)
with pool as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        # do sql stuff
        ...
```

To do this, we should `conn = pool.getconn()` from the pool, and, after we're done with the queries, `pool.putconn(conn)` it back. Seems like a perfect example of using the context manager.

Yet if we do:

```
# this function -> a part of ThreadedConnectionPool subclass
def __enter__(self):
    return self._pool.getconn()  # doesn't return self, returns a database connection
```

Then, you need to return the connection in the `__exit__` method. Something like:

```
# this function -> a part of ThreadedConnectionPool subclass
def __exit__(self, *args):
    self._pool.putconn(conn)  # <--- here!
    ...
```

but how do we access the `conn` object? It seems like it should be known to the context, **but where can it actually be accessed**?

I've read [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13565241/get-returned-by-enter-in-exit), but it this object is used in a multithreaded environment and stores a lot of connections simultaneously, so there is no chance we can use a local state variable, is there?

What can one do to access the `__enter__` return value in the `__exit__` function call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular object should only have one connection at a time.  So this should work:

```
    def __enter__(self):
        self.conn = self.__pool.getconn()
        return self.conn
    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.__pool.putconn(self.conn)
        self.conn = None
```

Comment: I suppose, I've overcomplicated the problem.

Comment: That's what programmers do.